# how to permanently turn off wired network in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits with wireless. But every time the computer starts up it is trying to connect to wired network, even if I'm already connected to wireless every 10 of 15 minutes it is trying to connect to wired, unless I am not going to network setup and turning off wired. But Ubuntu never remembers this change, after restart its the same...

Answer (score 1):

Try to untick the 'Connect automatically' box (or something else, i'm not using the english version of Ubuntu) in the wired connection settings.